# Is ipython a replacement or it works side by side with regular python?

Tags: python

Is ipython just a better shell environment that uses the same libs/packages that the regular python interpreter will use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is ipython just a better shell environment that uses the same libs/packages that the regular python interpreter will use?

Yes.  It is an advanced interactive shell and an environment for parallel computing (but most people only use it as an interactive shell).

Comment: can you point to resources that actually show how to use ipython as environment for parallel computing?

Comment: @Sam: Just look at the official documentation, in particular [the chapter on parallel computing](http://ipython.github.com/ipython-doc/stable/html/parallel/index.html).